# Word or phrase for someone devoid of logical reasoning/employs irrational thought?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase, pejorative or otherwise, for someone who is not equipped with the tools of rationality?  E.g.

**A**: "Every time I wear my lucky shirt I get more green traffic lights."

**B**: "Maybe you just notice green lights more when you are wearing your lucky shirt because you believe it to be lucky?"

**A**: "No, I definitely hit more green lights.  I wore it to the Super Bowl and hit every green on the way out the city."

**B**: "Oh, interesting.  Did you consider the lights may be configured that way to get better through flow of traffic in busy periods?  In traffic management they call it a 'green wave'."

**A**: "How would you know?  You don't even drive."

---

Or in political argument:

**A**: "The Holocaust is a lie."

**B**: "What make you say that?"

**A**: "I just know it."

**B**: "How do you know it?"

**A**: "My uncle is German, he says so."

Etc. Etc.

---

**Example sentence:** "*A* is such a [...], trying to have a rational argument with him is like bashing your head against a brick wall."

I feel like "airhead" or "simpleton" would come close but I feel that those imply stupidity and, in society's eyes, stupidity doesn't infer irrationality.

---

### Please note: I am not trying to infer madness or eccentricity.  More like "the opposite of someone you would find on a debate team."

Comment: I’d just call them an ***idiot***

Comment: My two cents on the words, but not sure what you're hoping for. I'm sort of partial to one of Ricky's three suggestions, 'dingbat'. While 'idiot' has it's strong merits, it's common use has come to mean "a-hole" and less it's original meaning of inherent mental shortcoming/disability. Some of the other answers people are giving refer to an intransigence of changing opinions without enough emphasis on the "beyond comprehension" feel which would make it almost impossible to even begin to address or try to understand where they are coming from to hope to use their own approach to sway them.

Comment: If you're looking for "someone who makes unclear arguments" .. you might try *Obtuse* , but all of your examples seem more like a matter of the person being delusional as much as unclear or dogmatic

Comment: Fallacious thinker, fallacious reasoner, fallacious arguer, fallacist, etc.

Comment: *Human being* seems like the most accurate term. There's plenty of research to show we mainly use "logic" to justify our emotional decision making after the fact.

Comment: Rather than inventing examples, why did you not throw that Question at your chosen dictionaries, thesauruses or search engines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about **irrationalist**?

TFD:

> [**irrationalist**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irrationalist): a
>   person who acts or behaves irrationally, or who holds irrational
>   beliefs
>
> [**irrational**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irrational):
>   inconsistent with reason or logic; illogical; absurd; incapable of
>   reasoning
>
> [**irrationalism**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irrationalism):
>   belief in feeling, instinct, or other nonrational forces rather than
>   reason

Answer (score 5):

You could call them a **dogmatist**.

> [one who is] characterized by or given to the expression of opinions very strongly or positively as if they were facts

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dogmatic

Comment: That's a nice one, I am wondering if there is a word which does not have connotations with proselytizing though.

Comment: Practically speaking, I suspect that because you're seeking such a specific meaning, you'd be better off using an adjective.  Having said that, from a purely academic perspective, I am curious if anyone can come closer.

Comment: Same. I do not think I have ever heard a word for it but am curious to know if one exists.  Fortunately I do not need to write it but, if I had to, I would probably go for "blissfully ignorant in the ways of rational argument" or something like that.

Comment: An intelligent person can often be dogmatic... disqualifying this word completely for me. (I'm being a bit dogmatic about that perhaps)

Answer (score 4):

I'd call them **"a blockhead"** or, depending on context, I'd say they're **"adamant"**.

A blockhead if such unfruitful debate is due to absence of logical reasoning.

> - [**blockhead**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blockhead) -  (derogatory) a person regarded as very stupid; a dolt.

and I'd call them adamant if the barren discussion is due to their temperament.

> - [**adamant**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adamant) - (adj)  unshakable in purpose, determination, or opinion; unyielding. Not willing to change one's opinion, purpose, or principles.

Answer (score 1):

**dingbat**

Slang. an eccentric, silly, or empty-headed person.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dingbat

**screwball**

Slang. an eccentric or whimsically eccentric person; a nut.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/screwball

Alternatively, you could say he's "**impervious to logic**."

Comment: Sorry, I feel all but your last phrase infer a sort of wackyness (e.g. Kramer form Seinfeld) but I am thinking about purely irrationality rather than eccentricity or anything else which may be considered abnormal.

Comment: I like dingbat because the person is prone to thoughts outside of normal reasoning .. to the point of empty-headedness.  I don't like screwball which I agree is more like Kramer - who had his own mad logic but not always a patently wrong logic.  (how do you argue that people would enjoy driving in wider lanes so he restriped the freeway section he adopted...thats screwball.. not wrong ... just missing the big picture).  As for "impervious to logic", that would be a pretty accurate description if I understand the OP right, but it misses another level that implies being irrationally wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure on the rules or what other people do, but it takes the fun out of it here when people put words with different nuances in the same answer... which one am I giving a thumbs up to? (so I don't)

Answer (score -1):

Die-hard (MWD)

> strongly or fanatically determined or devoted die–hardfans; especially :  strongly resisting change a die–hard conservative

Crackpot (MWD)

> one given to eccentric or lunatic notions

Answer (score -1):

To answer your first example, I'd call the person superstitious.

I think the other answers cover the second example pretty well.

Answer (score -1):

Sciolist: a person who pretends to be knowledgeable and well informed.

Sophist: a person who reasons with clever but fallacious arguments.

Comment: Hi Desmond, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of each word (linked to the source) and examples of its use. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: NB *sciolist* is an archaic usage, while a *sophist* is rational and uses logic, so I don't think either word suits what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use the opposite... "Illogical"

Comment: How does *illogical* fit the sentence "A is such a [...]"? Note also, an answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: As a Comment, obviously true.

As an Answer, Stack Exchange demands provenance.

Answer (score -2):

I'll simply call it "Sentiments" 
The person is simply being sentimental. that's it. you talk or argue based on what you feel and not based on reason and facts!

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to EL&U. I don't think this quite fits: "The person is such a *sentiments*" doesn't make sense. It's plural, for a start; but even as the singular noun *sentiment*, it's the wrong usage. Adding a dictionary definition to your answer is recommended not only for the information it provides, but as a useful check as you're drafting your answer. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)